# What are the differences difference between `lazy` class variables and `lazy` local variables in a closure?

Tags: scala, closures, lazy-evaluation, scalaz

In Scalaz in `object Need` I've found

```
def apply[A](a: => A) = {
  lazy val value0: A = a
  new Need[A] {
    def value = value0
  }
}
```

What's the difference between this and (more natural to me)

```
def apply[A](a: => A) = {
  new Need[A] {
    private lazy val value0: A = a
    def value = value0
  }
}
```

in terms of performance, generated code, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally prefer the second one in time- or space-critical applications.  The reason is buried in the bytecode.  Specifically, if we have

```
abstract class Foo { def value: Int }
class Bar {
  def out(i: => Int) = {
    lazy val v0 = i
    new Foo { def value = v0 }
  }
  def in(i: => Int) = new Foo {
    private lazy val v0 = i
    def value = v0
  }
}
```

then in the second case we add a private `v0: Int` and `bitmap$0: Boolean` to the bytecode, plus the standard lazy val accessors.  In the first case, however, we instead add a `v0$lzy$1: runtime.IntRef` and a `bitmap$0$1: runtime.VolatileByteRef` to refer to an equivalent `Int` and `Boolean` created in the body of the `out` method.  Thus, we have an extra layer of wrapping.

On my machine, the `out` version takes about 50% longer than the `in` version to create an object and retrieve `value` once.